# Foreach loops thru an object

Tags: php, object, foreach

How do i loop thru this object and read the `conversion_id`. I tried the following foreach, but i seems like I'm doing it wrong.

```
<?php
    foreach( $result->response->data as $key=>$value ) {
        echo $value->Stat->conversion_id.' ';
    }
?>





stdClass Object
(
    [response] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 1
            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [conversion_id] => 351140
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Stat] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [conversion_id] => 355704
                                        )
                                }
                        )
                )
        )

)
```

Comment: foreach only works with arrays. you'll have to loop through an array variable in that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed "data" and "Stat" objects:

```
<?php
    foreach( $result->response->data->data as $key=>$value ) {
        echo $value->Stat->conversion_id;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this, It's not giving me any results. I'm getting a warning `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Learn how to do an easy "php-way" debug =)  Just list all properties with `var_dump($result);`, `var_dump($result->response);` etc...

Answer (score 2):

You want to iterate over `$result->response->data->data`